# Angular Function not Called in <span> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table of data loaded. But I need the data on a particular column be generated by a function. And that function is not being called. I don't know why

**Function**

```
vm.itemName = '';

vm.getItemName = function (item) {
    termService.getItemName({ itemId: term.itemID })
     .then(function (result) {
           vm.itemName = JSON.stringify(result.data);
    });
};
```

**page.cshtml**

```
<td>
    <span>{{vm.itemName }}</span>
</td>
```

Whem the page is rendered the column is empty. When I debugged the application, I realized the function is not called.

N.B The function is calling a c# method through web API.

**EDITS**

I get the itemsList using this function below and it works perfectly.

```
vm.terms = [];

function getTermsList() {
    termService.getTermsList({}).success(function (result) {
       vm.terms = result.items;
    });
}
```

And my table grid looks like this so you know where 'item' comes from

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.terms">
        <td>....</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: when is vm.getItemName(item) called?

Comment: @Dimitri I need it to be called when data is loaded to the table. (Page load)

Comment: You need to call `vm.getItemName()` somewhere

Comment: @Michelem, I called the function instead before. But the page crashes.

Comment: Make sure your are using the controller name here <span>{{vm.itemName }}</span> ie, <span>{{cntrl.itemName }}</span>

Comment: You must call the function as Michelem said, and do you have var vm = this; at the top of your controller?  What is in result.data when you hover over it?

Comment: @JobinSKumar It is within the div tag that has the controller name. I doubt there is a need for that.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I can't tell because it doesn't get called in the first place.

Comment: see edits to my comment above.

Comment: We can't help...we don't know where the argument `item` in function needs to come from. Not enough information provided for that

Comment: All, I get an exception of XMLHttpRequest.w.onload() when I call the function like this `vm.getItemName(item)` in the span tag.

Comment: never make async requests from view functions that are being interpolated. Will run into all sorts of digest problems. We don't know enough bout what exactly you are trying to acheive

Comment: you are supposed to call vm.getItemName(); in your controller, not on your view.

Comment: Also, it seems you are calling a service.  What code is in your service?

Comment: @charlietfl Okay. Here is what I want to acheive. The data from database being generated when the page loads does fine. But I have a foreign key in the data `itemId` is present and I don't want it showing integer. I need it to show it's corresponding name. Any idea as to how I can achieve that? I'm finding it difficult to do it with MVC angular Application. I can do it with a pure MVC multipage application. I hope you understand.

Comment: it's fairly simple if we just know where `item` comes from but you haven't shown enough context. you would just call the service method in the controller and pass that item in without the extra function wrapper

Comment: @charlietfl please could you see edited question to know where the argument is coming from? Thanks.

Comment: @Kacey Ezerioha - Since every item in the initial data set would need its name, why not retrieve the name along with the data set? depending on your implementation, this might be as easy as a SQL JOIN.

Answer (score -1):

the "getter" are not called magically like when you work with SERVER SIDE rendering but we can me it work as you expect in this way:

```html
vm._itemName = '';
var itemNamePromise = null;
//define itemName getter
Object.defineProperty(vm, "itemName", { 
  get: function() {
    itemNamePromise = if(itemName === '' && itemNamePromise === null){ //to avoid multile service calls
      termService.getItemName({ itemId: term.itemID })
       .then(function (result) {
           vm._itemName = JSON.stringify(result.data);
      });
    }
    return vm._itemName;
  }
});
```

See reference for compatibility in:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get